# Send a private message to a specific role in Python

Tags: python, discord.py

How would I send a private message to a specific role in Python

Here's what I've already done:

```
@bot.command(name='dm')
async def on_message(ctx):
    
    role = get(ctx.guild.roles, id=839182749452992632)    
    for user in ctx.guild.members:
        if user.roles == role:
            await bot.send_message(user, 'hello')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`user.roles` returns a list, however you're only comparing it to a single `role` object. This will always be `False`. Instead, check if the desired role is in the `user.roles`. If so, check if there already is a DM with that user, otherwise create one and send the message.

```py
import asyncio

@bot.command(name='dm')
async def on_message(ctx):
    
    role = get(ctx.guild.roles, id=839182749452992632)

    for user in ctx.guild.members:
        if role in user.roles:
            if user.dm_channel is None:
                await user.create_dm()
            await user.dm_channel.send("hello")
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
```

You should however also include a delay, to not get flagged by discord anti-spam system

Comment: Thx @itzFlubby it solved my problem, btw, for this to work all users must allow direct messages from members of the server right?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure on that one, but I would say yes, they will have to allow direct messages from server members

Comment: I was testing it and the bot only send messages to me, do you have an ideia of whats the problem @itzFlubby? if not, np, i'll do more search about it

Comment: If the bot sends the message to you, it should also send it to everyone else with your specified role. If not, maybe print every user after `if role in user.roles:` to narrow down the problem. We could also move this to a [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/new) if you like

Comment: The bot is not sending the message to everyone because I am testing it on a server and people are giving me feedback, I will print all users to see what happens. Of course, we can move on to a chat, if you have time to help me I would be grateful @itzFlubby

Comment: Yes, I've got time and would be happy to help. We just need to generate a `move to discussion` url, which is done automatically if there are too many comments.. Sadly there is no way of doing this manually afaik, so we just need to spam to get that link

Comment: Ok, so we just need to spam comments?

Comment: Basically, tbh never done this before, but I heared this is the way to go ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I can automatically move this discussion to chat, but when i do it i says that i dont have enough reputation for that

Comment: You can earn reputation like defined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation)

Comment: Can i make a question and you upvote it so i can earn enough reputation?

Comment: You should ask a real question. Just asking a dummy question won't work, because it will get downvoted to oblivion by others... Maybe just ask something about what you're currently working on?

Comment: Ok, I'll do that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232812/discussion-between-bernardo-pereira-and-itzflubby).